# Clearing form fields in Ember 2.10

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm following a tutorial on building an ember 2.10 app. I've moved my validation logic out of my contact controller and placed it inside my contact model. I've placed my action (saveContact) in my contact routes file. 
I can save my new contact to Firebase database without error. I'm stuck on how to clear out my form.

My contact route file looks like

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {
    return this.store.createRecord('contact');
  },

  actions: {

    saveContact(newContact) {
      newContact.save().then((response) => {
        const email = this.get('model.email');
        const message = this.get('model.message')
        this.set('email', '');
        this.set('message', '');
      })
    }

  }

});
```

I'm trying to retrieve the current value in the form and set both message and email to empty strings.

I've run a test and console logged email to the console and it return undefined.

In the input fields, the value being passed in are model.email and model.message.

Has anyone else been stuck on this problem?

Comment: try `this.set('model.email', ''); this.set('model.message', '');` or you can just to `this.refresh()` it will call model hook and you will get new fresh contact model.

Comment: Thanks. this.refresh() worked. this.set('model.email, ' ') and this.set('model.message', ' ') where the first things I tried. I could submit the form values but the page just froze without resetting.

Comment: This is a little bit strange to create new record in model function. Creating record in store (without saving it) is not asynchronous process. So you can do it everywhere, not only in model. The intention of `model()` hook is to load something from api/database/file. I think in your case you should have contact-form component and there should be implemented the whole contact form logic. If you already have this component you can paste it and i'll see what can be done to improve the code.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh model on this route try calling

```
this.refresh()
```

This will fire `beforeModel`, `model`, and `afterModel` hooks so you will get new contact model. [Reference](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh)